# having issue with the python parser. My function always returns 1. Whats wrong with it?

Tags: python

I am trying to ping 2 devices and parse the ping output.
Even when my ping is success, I am not able to grep the sucess.

Whats wrong with it?

```
['Type escape sequence to abort.\r', 'Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 100.30.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:\r', 'Packet sent with a source address of 10.10.0.1 \r', '!!!!!\r', 'Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms\r', '']

def ping_the_br(router,src,dst):
    cmd = 'ping '+dst+' so '+src
    router.execute(cmd)
    Op = router.execute(cmd)
    output = Op.split('\n')
    for line in output:
        if re.search(r'Success rate is 100 ',line):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

Comment: Because you are calling `return` in a loop, and the first line of output doesn't match, so you `return 1` at that point.  The loop never runs more than a single iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search all output lines before giving up and returning '1' so move that return statement outside the loop:

```
def ping_the_br(router, src, dst):
    cmd = 'ping ' + dst + ' so ' + src
    router.execute(cmd)
    runOutput = router.execute(cmd)
    output = runOutput.split('\n')
    for line in output:
        if re.search(r'Success rate is 100 ', line):
            return 0
    return 1
```

Also, you could avoid the split and just search the runOutput string, newlines and all, using appropriate search flags.